# rogue process consumes too much memory in linux

Tags: linux, process, rootkit

I was going through the output of top when i saw a process listed as

```
pine -i
```

I don't have pine in my system !
Then i got into proc and did a

```
`ls -l /proc/9827/exe`
```

9827 is the process id. It points to a directory like

```
 /home/ff/notes/pinb/test
```

I looked into the directory and found nothing. There is nothing like test in my directory.

Then I used unhide (all options)- which didn't detect anything at all.
Then I used chkrootkit , it didnt find anything amiss either.

I tried killing that process but it returns everytime after a reboot. What should I do ?

Comment: Did you look through the init scripts to see what's starting it?  That might give you a clue.

Comment: I did not find anything in that directory, there is nothing like test in it. It contains only my assignment pdfs. init script is untouched. I checked twice. It actually comes up some-time may be a few minutes (6 - 10) after the system starts.

Comment: I meant the system init scripts, in `/etc/init.d`...

Comment: It could very well be that your root password has been compromised. Disconnect from the network (Physically - _actually unplug it_), reboot, and see what happens.

Comment: Tyler Eaves, it still starts after some time as I said earlier.

Comment: Sounds like tools.l0t3k.net/Rootkit/psf.c.  Sounds like you got rooted.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like time to wipe and reinstall  to me. That certainly smells like you've been rooted. chkrootkit isn't infallible.

Comment: Please suggest more solutions. Re-install is the last thing which I am willing to do. Its not my box actually. I was actually surprised that unhide and chkrootkit both failed miserably.

Comment: This is a situation where you _don't screw around_. Something is clearly going on that you don't understand, know about, or control.

Answer (score 1):

You can use watch to watch logs then && `killall nameofprocess`. Read the man on watch. That pine proccess will be in `/etc/init.d/`. Somewhere so do.

```
Cd /etc/init.d/
ls -R * | grep pine
```

And that should tell you where it is and you can remove it from your startup. Better than watch running constantly too.